# Calling pandas apply function on results of a mask

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a function to a subset of rows in my dataframe based on some condition described in a mask. E.g:

```
mask = (n.city=='No City Found')
n[mask].city = n[mask].address.apply(lambda x: find_city(x))
```

When I do this, pandas warns me that I'm trying to set a value on a copy of a Dataframe slice. When I inspect the Dataframe, I see that my changes have not persisted.

If I create a new Dataframe slice x using *mask* and apply the function to x, the results of the apply function are correctly stored in x.

```
x = n[mask]
x.city = x.address.apply(lambda x: find_city(x))
```

Is there a way to map this data back to my original Dataframe such that it only affects rows that meet the conditions described in my original mask?

Or is there an easier way altogether to perform such an operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way to update values is using `loc`

```
n.loc[mask, 'city'] = n[mask].address.apply(lambda x: find_city(x))
```

You can also do it without the mask, in case you want to save the memory of the variable

```
n['city']=n.address.apply(
    lambda x: find_city(x)
    if x.city == 'No City Found' else x.city, axis=1
)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Using loc still results in a warning but the operation is persisted within n. The second example is very useful as I hadn't thought about using a conditional inside apply. Makes things a lot easier!